# Swap images with onclick

Tags: javascript, mouseevent

I have an incomplete script here that just needs to give a few adjustments of positions and add the exchange of images with the function Onclick of JavaScript but do not remember how to do more this exchange I would like to know what the error of the following code and how to fix, since I thank you.

```
// Like Normal e like Marcado
var imgLike01 = "images/mylike.png"
var imgLike02 = "images/like.png"
// Deslike Normal e deslike desmarcado
var imgDeslike01 = "images/mydeslike.png"
var imgDeslike02 = "images/deslike.png"

var likebtn = document.getElementById("likebtn");
var deslikebtn = document.getElementById("deslikebtn");

function like () {
likbtn.img.src = imgLike02;
}

function deslike () {
deslikebtn.img.src = imgDeslike02;
}

function Trade(){

if ($like).click(function() {
likbtn.img.src = imgLike01;
});

if ($deslike).click(function() {
deslikebtn.img.src = imgDeslike01;
});


}
```

Note This is the exchange of images from an old like system in JavaScript, a sum script and only missing image switching.

Comment: In `if` you can write conditions/expressions that evaluates to `true/false` not the user events. Ofcourse you can also write events, and that is to check the event codes like `event.keyCode`

Answer (score 0):

Add an `eventListener` to `likebtn`:

```
likebtn.addEventListener("click", like);
```

Do the same for `deslikebtn`.